# Building a login form w Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, authentication, jwt, dio

:)

I am a junior web dev and just got my hands on flutter and i need your help. I like flutter and was able to build various static website. For this projekt i need some assistence. I appreciate any kind of help!

Goal: Build a login form which interacts with the serverside app and the database.

Initial position:
Backend app already is working (developed with nodejs).
Database -> mongodb is used. We have an email, password for to be logged in. (Data is already in DB)
LoginAPI has been tested and works like it should.
In flutter ive created an Form which is static for now.

My issue is i don’t know how to exactly build the login and the API communication with the backend.
I heard about dio package and tried some stuff out but didnt rly been successful with it.

Can someone maybe show how you would develop this ? Like how you would make it and then also an small explanation of the code would be very very helpful for me.

I feel like when i am searching in youtube and googling arround that i m wasting my time, because thats what ive been doing and hadnt any success.

Also as you guys see -> i m a junior so if you guys have any kind of advice for the programing world, would really like to hear that. This is also my very first stackoverflow ticket, so sorry in advance if i did smth which is not tend to be.

Thank in advance, hav a nice day!

Answer (score 0):

There are many ways to handle login.
You can make an HTTP call from your project with the help of

`final response = await http.post(Uri.parse(baseUrl));`

and within the base URL, you can put the login URL with username and password. And when you will get the response, you can get whether it is true or false. If the API is passing you any SID or any token then you can save those to stored preference to set that the user has logged in. In the case of the web, you can set these things in cookies.

Comment: thx! will check out